# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 in legacy mode along with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I own a Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 with Windows 8 pre-installed on it. However, I have successfully installed Windows 7 in the legacy mode and deleted Windows 8 from my system. I also want to install Ubuntu in the legacy mode alongside Windows 7, but, the problem I'm facing regarding the installation is when I boot it from the live USB and try to install Ubuntu choosing "Something Else" option with the installation type, the system shows 1 TB as the available free space. I don't understand why is it showing the full hard drive being available even though I have Windows 7 installed in 100 GB partition. Please help me sort this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the option to install beside windows.  It will give you the option of resizing windows partition if necessary.

Also, you can open Disks or Gparted to see the list of partitions.